# Mule ESB -- Introduce a Middleware to Publish and Consume SOAP

Tags: web-services, soap, mule, mule-el

I just have started using Mule 3.8 CE version. My use case is to like this,

Publish SOAP -- Hit any method from Published SOAP -- Receive data   -- Pass this Data to consume SOAP -- Fetch Response -- Process response via Java -- Return this as response from Method of Published SOAP.

In short I want to introduce a middleware (not a proxy) from Mule which will publish endpoint (e1) -- receive data from that endpoint (e1) -- pass this data to another endpoint(e2) -- receive data from this another endpoint.(e2) -- return response to original endpoint (e1).

[image: My Mule Flow]

Currently I am using following Mule configuration to achieve this,

```
 <http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8085" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
<endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" address="http://192.168.2.3:9080/crestelBEExport/billexport/CrestelBEExportService/CrestelBEExport" name="Generic" doc:name="Generic"/>
<flow name="webserviceproducerFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/hello" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <cxf:jaxws-service serviceClass="com.poc.example.ws.IHelloWorld" doc:name ="CXF" />
    <component class="com.poc.example.ws.HelloWorldWSImpl" doc:name="Java"/>
</flow>
```

In the 'HellowWorldWSImpl" I have Webmethod. I am consuming SOAP and receive data in this webmethod. I am returning this data consumed from SOAP as response to this Webmethod. Is this right approach or is there any better way to achieve my requirement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Mule 3.8 enterprise edition, you have a feature, which will help you to specify WSDL in the beginning 
This will create similar structure like a RAML[Sample WSDL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ewahb.jpg)

Comment: I am using Mule CE only.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WS Consumer](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/web-service-consumer) for calling the WS. No need in writing java code. This will be more "mule" way.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I pass data to to WS Comsumer component because I already have published one WS from where I will be receiving data.